# Chat room name ideas?

Tags: discussion, chat

Arts & Crafts has it's own beloved chatroom!!! Woot!

The issue is, a few things.

1. Make sure to chat! Discuss! Chat's your third home, feel free to take about the site, or even just have casual discussion about arts and crafts here!
2. Umm... we need a name.

A [fantastic <s>troublemaker</s> angel](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/users/58/zizouz212) came about and assisted in making the chatroom better. However, blue people aren't normally the best at making changes. Besides, don't we want some community input?

[Matt suggested a great name](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29273588#29273588) - but should we keep it?

Like always, come join us at...

## [The Imagination Fabrication Station!!!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38932/imagination-fabrication-station)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

#### The Studio

?

Art studio
or Craft studio could be considered as well, but it looks like 'Studio' is the favourite one of these 3.

Comment: I like **The Studio**

Comment: We can't really vote on this because there are three options in one.

Comment: Well, okay, make it 'Studio' then. Sometimes it's better to go for the simple option.

Comment: In that case, could you edit this so it's clear in the answer body which option you're mainly proposing? (I can't suggest edits on meta.) Also, +1: I tried to come up with a good name for the chatroom, and the best idea I had was "The Studio" :-)

Comment: FYI, this is now the room name unless votes swing wildly to the top in another direction. Make sure to join us.

Answer (score 4):

### The Drawing Board

It relates to drawing, but *primarily*  the planning of projects of all types. There's the popular phrase:

> Back to the drawing board

Comment: I like it, but there's a very strong association with drawn arts (a possibly small subset of the site's focus).

Comment: @Erica That's true, but I'm used to having that on SFF! It's hard to come up with a generic name, but I'll keep the hamster running.

Comment: I like this one with the logic you have given. After all, every project should start with planning and planning is done on the drawing board.

Comment: +1 "board" can also be understood as a group of people ("board of directors"). Since chat is often used for discussing everything related to our main & meta sites, I think this is perfect! And "drawing board" in the sense of "[a] large flat board on which paper may be spread for artists or designers to work on" is relevant for crafts as well.

Comment: General chat can be called "The Drawing Board" then if there was enough traction we could have "The Gallery" as a secondary room that can be for showing off work.

Comment: @Matt I love that idea!

Answer (score 4):

### The Gallery

An art gallery is a place where you view arts & crafts and often discuss the pieces. Galleries are meant for artists and those who appreciate art both.

It is also, hopefully, a little more inclusive of a variety of arts & crafts.

Answer (score 0):

Matt's name is great!

Keep it named the Imagination Fabrication Station!

Comment: I feel my upvote for this is biased but so be it.

Comment: Sorry... clearly I'm really boring but this seems a bit too... upbeat for my tastes. It feels like the uber-peppy name for something in a children's museum.

Comment: @Catija lol. That's okay. Some people aren't energetic like me. Guess that goes to say I'm still a child (or immature teenager). :P

Comment: The Imagination Fabrication Station will probably soon be abbreviated to TIFS, which could mean Tractus Iliotibialis Friction Syndrome... hmmm....

Answer (score 0):

**The Creative Outlet**

I think Matt's second suggestion is worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

**Blank Sheet**

This represents the blank sheet of ideas that is being filled in the chat room.

Answer (score -2):

For the mod chatroom:

[AICA](http://aicainternational.org/en/)

Comment: Hmm... Already thinking of the super top secret places for blue people... I see :P

Comment: @Zizouz212 Blue lives matter